# Is there any continuous surjective map from $[0,1) $ to $\mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Is there any continuous surjective map from $[0,1) $ to $\mathbb R$?

If it exits then what is the way to construct such a map?

Comment: Consider steoreografic projection in the real line.

Comment: Why is that surjective?

Comment: Note that $[0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $[0,\infty)$.  So it's enough to find any continuous function on the non-negative reals that is unbounded both above and below.  Many can be visualized, for example any continuous function passing through the points $(n,(-1)^n n)$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like $$f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}\sin \frac{1}{1-x}$$ does the trick.

You wouldn't have one if $f$ also had to be injective.

Comment: To give some heuristics: The image of $[0,a]$ is compact, in particular bounded for any $a<1$. This means that for $x$ close to $1$, you need a sequence, the function takes to $\infty$ and a sequence the function takes to $-\infty$. The intermediate value theorem of course tells you that this is not only neccessary but also sufficient for surjectivity. So you are searching for a function, that jumps betweens positive and negative numbers. Of course sine and cosine come to mind immediately.